# Powershell: Can sort an array, but can't get unique values

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am collecting some user info from AD and trying to sort it, then remove duplicates, but I can't seem to get sort -unique to work:

```
foreach ($pute in $puters){
    $user = get-loggedinuser -computer $pute.name | select -expandproperty username
    $fullname = get-aduser $user | select -expandproperty name
    $fullnames += $fullname
}
$fullnames = $fullnames | sort -unique
```

What this gives me is something like:
Adam Warlock
Adam Warlock
Bruce Biggalow
Frank Coutel
Frank Coutel
Tony Shaloub

Where the output is sorted, but the duplicates remain.

Comment: What is `get-loggedinuser`?

Comment: what type is $fullnames? it might be viewed as a normal string. Try defining it as [string[]] or a collection

Comment: Get-Loggedinuser is a function written by Jiten (https://community.spiceworks.com/people/jitensh). I'll try redefining $fullnames as a string and comment back.

Comment: edited code to resemble [string[]] fullnames += $fullname, but the results were the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update*: The **problem turned out to be the lack of initialization of `$fullnames` *as an array*, with `$fullnames = @()`** (in the absence of this initialization, `+=` perform simple *string concatenation* instead of appending an element to an array, conceptually speaking).

The answer below may still be of interest for diagnosing how identical-*looking* strings may differ.

---

**Since your `Sort-Object` inputs are *strings*** (and the name-per-line output implies that `$fullnames` is indeed an *array*, even though you don't show its initialization as such), the implication is that **the *ostensible* duplicates must differ by *whitespace (type)* or *invisible control characters***.

You can try the following technique to **discover such invisible discrepancies**:

```sh
'Adam Warlock',
'Adam Warlock ',  # trailing space
'Frank Coutel',
('Frank{0}Coutel' -f [char] 0xa0) | # no-break space instead of regular space
  ForEach-Object { $_ + "`t" + [int[]] [char[]] $_ } |
    Sort-Object -Unique
```

Output:

```sh
Adam Warlock    65 100 97 109 32 87 97 114 108 111 99 107
Adam Warlock    65 100 97 109 32 87 97 114 108 111 99 107 32 # Note the extra 32
Frank Coutel    70 114 97 110 107 160 67 111 117 116 101 108 # Note the 160
Frank Coutel    70 114 97 110 107 32 67 111 117 116 101 108
```

The numbers are the Unicode *code points* of the characters that make up each string, in decimal format.

---

Alternatively, for a **better visualization of the differences**, use helper function `Debug-String` from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/7f2f1e13ac9c2afaf0a0906d08b392d1):

- Note: The following snippet downloads and defines the function automatically. I can personally assure you that doing so is safe, but you you should always check the source code yourself first.

```sh
# Download and define helper function Debug-String
#  * See comments above.
#  * To see instructions on how to make the function available in 
#    *future* sessions, remove >3 $null and re-run this command directly
#    from the command line.
irm https://gist.github.com/mklement0/7f2f1e13ac9c2afaf0a0906d08b392d1/raw/Debug-String.ps1 | iex 3>$null

'Adam Warlock',
'Adam Warlock ',  # trailing space
'Frank Coutel',
('Frank{0}Coutel' -f [char] 0xa0) | # no-break space instead of regular space
  Debug-String |
    Sort-Object -Unique
```

Output:

```sh
Adam·Warlock
Adam·Warlock·      # Note the trailing · 
Frank·Coutel
Frank`u{a0}Coutel  # Note the `u{a0} escape sequence
```

`Debug-String` visualizes regular spaces as `·`, and formatting/control characters outside the ASCII range as Unicode escape sequences, e.g. `` `u{a0} ``, where `a0` is the hex form of the character's Unicode code point, namely of the [*no-break space* (  `U+00A0`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0) character, in this case.

Comment: Implemented debug-string and compared the output. the portions of the list that match, like Adam Warlock in the example, still match with the hidden formatting/control characters exposed.  E.g. Adam Warlock now shows up as AdamÂ·ÂWarlock, and all copies match.

Comment: @SpaceCoyote300, A much simpler way to collect all names is to use the `foreach` loop _as an expression_: `$fullnames = foreach ($pute in $puters) {
    $user = get-loggedinuser -computer $pute.name | select -expandproperty username;
     get-aduser $user | select -expandproperty name
}`, which also ensures that `$fullnames` receives an _array_ of names (assuming two or more output objects).

Comment: Also, the `Â` character you quote as `Debug-String` output would indicate that UTF-8 encoded names are being misinterpreted as ANSI strings, and I wouldn't know how that could happen with `Get-ADUser` output - unless the names are truly stored in this misinterpreted form in AD.

Comment: You mentioned that I wasn't declaring the arrays ahead of initialization, which was the problem. I added declarations for my arrays and they started working properly. Thank you.